# Get windows login name without Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-authentication, winlogon

I am trying to get the windows Logon username from my asp.net application. Here is my code

```
string user_name = Request.ServerVariables.Get("LOGON_USER");
```

this is works fine on my local environment but when I upload the same code on the IIS it gives me blank, even I have tried to get logon username by

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

but it gives me blank. Once I enable IIS authentication to Windows authentication and disable Antonyms Authentication it is working fine. Can anyone please guide me how I will get this. Please correct me if I am using any wrong approch.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I don't want to set Windows Authentication, so, Will it be possible in ASP.NET page  level authentication by setting in Web.Config

```
<allow user="*"/> or <deny user="?"/>
```

Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to get the user name of the user that is authenticated or do you want to get the user name of the user, running your process? In the first case you have to enable windows authentication. If the user is not authenticated (or anonymously authenticated), how should the application determinate the users credentials?

Comment: @Aschratt thanks for reply. I want the user logon who want to access the system. My application is not an intranet based. It can be accessed from outside world also. Can it will be possible ?

Comment: This is not possible. User accounts are stored localy on the user's system or within a domain controller if the system is registered with a domain. The identity can only be ensured within this scope and therefor you cannot use it from your web application. It would also be a huge security issue if anyone could request the username I am using to login to my system.

Comment: So you mean without windows authentication it will not possible for me to retrieve the logon username, right?

Comment: Even with enabling windows authentication, you cannot access the user's local logon name. You can create an own server-side user directory. There you can create users that can be used to authenticate with your application, but you simply cannot access user credentials that you do not manage!

Comment: thanks @Aschratt, one last question if I enable the windows authentication then will it possible to connect my application from everywhere? As I have tried that but it will only accepts the deployed servers loginname and password only. It will not accept local login details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get username, you need to use something besides anonymous authentication.

Using Anonymous authentication, you cannot get the username of a local user.  Even if this were possible, it would not be practical with a public facing site b/c you could have multiple computers with the same local username.

Also, since you mentioned that this is an external facing site outside of a corporate domain, then Windows Authentication is not an option.  Windows Authentication is mainly used for internal intranet applications.

What you likely are looking for if you want to uniquely ID each user, and have  is Forms authentication, which ASP.NET supports and provides an out of the box controls for allowing users to register and create accounts for your website.  Check out this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4.aspx

To answer: "Will it be possible in ASP.NET page level authentication by setting in Web.Config?"
Setting the authorization rules of `<allow user="*"/> or <deny user="?"/>` in web.config controls the `authorization` for a given user (whether or not a given user can get to a page in this case) AFTER the user has been `authenticated`, but does not have an impact on the `authentication` method or the membership provider used.  So this web.config setting will not allow you to get a username using anonymous authentication.