# Windows Authentication - Allow anyone

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-8

In an ASP.NET, C# application, i'd like to get the user's login. So i set up windows authentication, and because it's ONLY to get the login, i allowed (i think ?) anyone.

```
    <anonymousIdentification enabled="false"/>
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate ="true"/>
<authorization>
  <allow users="*"/>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

And locally, it was working as i expected, the user wasn't getting any form requesting credentials or something, but when i deployed my project to a distant IIS, even with anonymous login disabled, impersonation enabled, and the same config file, it asks the credential

why :(

EDIT : to be more precise, my website is an intranet, and isn't supposed to ever get out of local network.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984995/get-windows-login-name-without-windows-authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user browses to the website, their credentials are used to execute the application. Since the Window's users do not have the necessary permissions on the remote server, they are receiving the enter your credential screen.

[Microsoft reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5.aspx)

> When impersonation is enabled, only your application code runs under
>   the context of the impersonated user.

How to fix the problem?

Set impersonate to "false"

Comment: it's not working :( should add an user or something ?

Comment: plus, it's weird, because when i run the app in vusal studio with IIS express, i doesn't ask anyting, an dit does when i deploy the project on IIs 8

Comment: When using Visual Studio your permissions are passed to the application.

Comment: Grant access to the Windows authenticated user group.

Comment: sorry, but how do i do that ? (thanks for helping btw)

Comment: See this link about the "Authenticated User" group http://blog.varonis.com/the-difference-between-everyone-and-authenticated-users/

Comment: You would add this group to the web application's folder. This should address any ACL issue you would encounter.

Comment: i'm new to iss, even if i get what your link meant, i don't know what to do with this information

Comment: What version of Windows server are you running?  This will help me isolate the version of IIS you are using.b I can then create a tutorial based upon your version.

Comment: thank you very much :) i have windows server 2012 with IIS 8